# How do I update MySQL to join table data

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this form that lists certain collectible cards:

[image: Table Form]

Here the user can select the items he has and leave unchecked the ones he doesn't have.

I have the form.php passing these checkboxes like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stickerID[]" value="<?php echo $row['stickerID']; ?> ">
```

And this posts to editform.php which looks like this:

```
<?php

//echo results
foreach($_POST['stickerID'] as $k=>$v ){
echo $k;
echo "=>";
echo $v;
}


//UPDATE user_items SET stickerStatus = 1 WHERE stickerID = $_POST["stickerID"];

?>
```

which at the moment simply prints out the values for the selected sticker cards:

```
0=>0 1=>1 2=>2
```

where cards 0, 1 & 2 show up as selected.

My database looks like this:

```
users table with userID, userName, userEmail
user_items with userItemID, userID, itemID
Sheet1 with stickerID, stickerName, stickerSection, stickerStatus
```

This is because thats how I started building it.  But I realize the selection must not be stored in the Sheet1 table, but somewhere else.  Im kinda seeing it, but not quite.  How should I store where each user has or doesn't have that card?  It should be in the user_item table somehow, shouldn't it?

Comment: user_items, probably? You've already got itemID/userID tuples. If a record is present, then that user has that item, basically.

Comment: Oh!  I think I see...